# help needed regarding a suitable GUI control in struts

Tags: user-interface, struts2

hey all..
i want the user to enter a set of data such as "name" and "age" and correspondingly send it to the person bean. But the user can choose to enter any number of person's data at 1 go.
What control at GUI would be suitable for achieving this (keeping in mind i am developing the application in stuts2).

Thanks;!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't going to be anything definitive. Just hand roll the solution with your favorite JS library. Adding struts2-json-plugin will probably help.

I had created something very much like what you are looking for... It was a two column table where you typed in a user name into one field, hit tab, then typed in the second field.  There was one button at the end of the table, so hitting tab once more and enter added the current fields to the DB and added a new row to the table and positioned the input into the first field.  It allowed for smooth data entry.